# Data Pipeline failing for EMR Activity

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to run a spark step on AWS Data-pipeline. I am getting the following exception:-

> amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Failed to
>   complete EMR transform. at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:67)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81)
>   at
>   private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76)
>   at
>   private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: EMR job
>   '@DefaultEmrActivity1_2017-11-20T12:13:08_Attempt=1' with jobFlowId
>   'j-2E7PU1OK3GIJI' is failed with status 'FAILED' and reason 'Cluster
>   ready after last step completed.'. Step
>   'df-0693981356F3KEDFQ6GG_@DefaultEmrActivity1_2017-11-20T12:13:08_Attempt=1'
>   is in status 'FAILED' with reason 'null' at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil.runSteps(EmrUtil.java:286) at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:63)
>   ... 7 more

The cluster is getting spun up correctly.

Here is the screenshot of the pipeline:-

[image: screenshot]

I think there is some issue with the 'step' in activity. Any input would be helpful.

Comment: This is unsalvageable without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and the whole error stack.

Comment: I will upload the whole error stack.Meanwhile,1) is there anything faulty in the steps, as in the spark-submit command? As per:-http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html, we are supposed to use commas right? 2) We can use S3 for inputs right?

Comment: Have you tried to spin up a cluster and submit a similar Spark step manually? The trace does not expose the cause of the failure: `Step 'df-0693981356F3KEDFQ6GG_@DefaultEmrActivity1_2017-11-20T12:13:08_Attempt=1' is in status 'FAILED' with reason 'null'`. Can you access to the logs on S3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the:-
1) script should have been comma-separated. Something like:-

```
command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,com.amazon.Main
```

Link:- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emrcluster.html

2) EmrActivity does not support Staging. So, we cannot use `${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR}` in the step instruction. Currently, I have replaced this with the hardcoded S3 URL's.